# AspNetUserRoles en ASP NET MVC EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola amigos tengo la siguiente situación, para todos los que han usado **EF** me imagino que habrán cargado una bd por **ADO.Net Entity Data Model** esto te ayuda a generar tablas y conectarse un serv de SQL, normalmente te crea ciertas tablas, en particular me refiero a estas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que ya cuando cargo la base de datos y veo el diagrama que **VS** genera, no me agrega la tabla **AspNetUserRoles** no sé a que se deba. Si lo busco en mi explorador **SQL SERVER OBJECT EXPLORER** si aparece, pero incluso en las clases que se generan dentro del modelo (Entity Data Model) no aparece la clase **AspNetUserRoles**
Estuve tratando de hacer un query a esta tabla así

```
        public JsonResult ROLESID() {
        //AspNetUserRoles
        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;


          //  var studentName = db..SqlQuery("select UserId,RoleId from AspNetUserRoles").FirstOrDefault<UserRolesIds>();

            string sqlString =
                " select UserId,RoleId from AspNetUserRoles";

            var objctx = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

            ObjectQuery<UserRolesIds> userRol = objctx.CreateQuery<UserRolesIds>(sqlString);
            UserRolesIds roles = userRol.First<UserRolesIds>();

            return Json(roles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

y con esta clase :

```
    public class UserRolesIds
{
   public string UserId { get; set; }
   public string RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

Pero me tira el siguiente error

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntitySqlException: ''UserId' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 1, column 9.'

A todo esto los unicos campos de esa tabla son `RoleId nvarchar(128)` y  `UserId nvarchar(128)`. Alguien sabe como puedo manejar esta situación? si hay algo que me estoy saltando? o porque no me aparece **AspNetUserRoles** ?

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, pudiste resolverlo?

Answer (score 1):

No se genera el modelo de `AspNetUserRoles` ya que las operaciones relacionados a los Roles es manejado con `System.Web.Security`

Ejemplo:

```
//Agrega un rol
Roles.CreateRole("nombreRole");
// si requieres agregar usuario a rol 
 Roles.AddUserToRole("userNameToAddToRole", "selectedRoleName"); 
//obtiene los usuarios dentro de roles
Roles.GetUsersInRole("nombrerole");
//obtiene todos los roles
Roles.GetAllRoles();
```